# Evaluate the given integral by changing to polar coordinates. (how to integrate $\sin(r^2)r$ with respect to $r$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

> Evaluate the given integral by changing to polar coordiantes.
>
> $\int\int_R \sin(x^2+y^2)\, dA$, where $R$ is the region in the first quadrant between the circles with center the origin and radii $1$ and $3$.

I know how to set up the integral but when I have $\int_1^3 \sin(r^2)r\,dr\,d\theta$ I'm not sure how to integrate with respect to $r$. I tried using $u$ substitution for both $\sin$ and $r^2$, but it didn't seem to eliminate the right variables. I don't think I can treat  $\sin(r^2)$ as a constant, or if can just use u substitution on $r^2$ to get $-\cos r^2$. Can someone tell me if either of these are ok or which are the correct ways to integrate this? I couldn't find any examples leading me to believe either of these are ok.

Comment: mathjax guide, surround mathy object with dollar sign, use \int for integration $\int$, \sin for $\sin$ , \theta for $\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=r^2$, $\frac{du}{dr}=2r$

$$\int \sin(r^2) r \, dr=\int\sin(u)\frac12\, du$$

Comment: oh ok, i didn't think the answer would end up being weird like pi(cos1-cos9)/4

Comment: @2316354654 Don't forget the $\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta$, though.